# Are use-once datatypes in MPI a correct and/or acceptable design?

Tags: c, types, mpi, commit, registration

This below is prototypical MPI program that uses datatypes.
The code is a simplified version of this example: https://mpi.deino.net/mpi_functions/MPI_Type_vector.html .
As many other examples, the MPI datatypes are created and commited once and used many times.

I modified it so that the type created and committed next to the MPI message passing inside a function (`f`).
This example is made to ask if it is correct to call the function `f` repeatedly, given that `f` created and commit types in every call.

Somehow I expected that committing types for "one-time use" would be erroneous.

However the program runs fine and doesn't consume more memory when repeating the call more times.

**Is it in general fine to create a type, committing it (and destroy it) many times?**

I was expecting that the program will eventually fail because the types are committed repeatedly and that would consume more and more memory.
(That is, a datatype committed would consume resources.)
Specially because there is no "uncommit" function in MPI.
There is another alternative that is that `MPI_Type_free` is smart enough to also "uncommit" the datatype.
In many places I read that MPI "compiles" datatype once committed, so it is possible that this is done "inplace" in the datatype handle.

For a moment I though that this is because the MPI system detects that the same type is being committed and the commit wasn't doing anything (i.e. the commit was ignored after a check).
But when I create types with all different parameters still there is no extra consumption of memory.

**NOTE**: I understand that creating the datatype and committing is not free and there is a runtime overhead but in the case where `stride` is a runtime variable this simplifies the design of a program because you don't need to have a global variable or a global registration function.
Besides if the parameter of the type changes at runtime a pre-registration is not possible.
The question is if these datatypes commits really take memory when called repeatedly and if this design is correct if one wants to create the types on usage rather than globally.
There is nothing to this respect in the MPI manuals, there are only examples in which registration happens once and the type is used many times.

```c
#include "mpi.h"
#include<assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// can this be called unlimited number of times?
void f(int stride, int* buffer, int rank){
    MPI_Datatype type, type2;

    MPI_Type_contiguous(3, MPI_INT, &type2);
    MPI_Type_commit(&type2);
    MPI_Type_vector(3, stride, 3, type2, &type);
    MPI_Type_commit(&type);

    if(rank == 0){
        for(int i=0; i<24; i++) buffer[i] = i;
        MPI_Send(buffer, 1, type, 1, 123, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }

    MPI_Status status;
    if (rank == 1){
        for(int i=0; i<24; i++) buffer[i] = -1;
        MPI_Recv(buffer, 1, type, 0, 123, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    }
    MPI_Type_free(&type);  // this is important and doesn't affect one committed
    MPI_Type_free(&type2);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int rank, size;
    int buffer[24];


    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    assert(size == 2);

    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    // one time call is ok, is many calls correct too?
    // for(int n = 0; n != 100000000; ++n) f(3, buffer, rank);
    f(3, buffer, rank);

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As long as you are freeing the datatype once it's not longer needed, repeated creation and destruction is totally fine. Still, if you are creating exactly the same type each and every time (like `type2` in your code), it is better to only create it once for the sake of performance. Also, you don't need to commit `type2` since you are never using it directly for communication and you may even free it right after the creation of `type`.

Comment: I dare not say that this is a widely used approach, but then MPI datatypes themselves are not widely used and are often abused. Still, at some point, it was the recommendation of the MPI forum that very large messages are dealt with through the creation of ad-hoc derived datatypes - see the BigMPI library.

Comment: @HristoIliev, thank you for your comment. For a long time I though that it was a mistake to do so and it prevented me to use datatypes. Mainly because I was not able to encapsulate the type abstraction and I had to deal with global state or pass along a lot of information (custom) from the top of the program. About your comment point: 1) I assume that the expensive operation is `commit`, right? Yes, my main application is big data, so far I have been serializing the data to auxiliary buffers but that eventually would not scale.

Comment: `MPI_Type_commit` is supposed to somehow "bless" the datatype and make it usable with the underlying network. Unless you have some very special HCA and fabric that can do a lot of communication offloading, commit is either a no-op or it does some optimisation of the underlying type description list, which is relatively cheap compared to the actual data transfer.

Comment: That was the rationale behind the forum's decision to not extend the MPI specification with support for large messages - creation of a derived datatype is deemed to be a relatively fast operation compared to the physical transfer of 2+ GiB of data.

Comment: Thanks I was asking about comparing the creating with committing steps. (I know both are supposed to be cheap compared to communication).

Comment: @HristoIliev MPI-4 will add large count support. While datatype overhead is negligible compared to moving gigabytes on the wire, there were other reasons to add it (the BigMPI paper has details).

Comment: @Jeff, thanks. Last time I spoke with M. Schulz in Dec, he said that big count was not a sure thing yet. Do you have new information?

Comment: It was decided in February that large count support is a gating feature for MPI-4. It passed first vote in June (https://www.mpi-forum.org/meetings/2020/06/votes).

Comment: Second vote passed. Large count support is in MPI-4 pending resolution of errata. https://github.com/mpi-forum/mpi-issues/issues/137